# Google Analytics Embedded API in Angular 5

Tags: angular, google-analytics, angular5

I've been searching information regarding this but I couldn't find a way to do it using Angular. Can anyone help me or guide me to face this? 
Im trying to do the typical admin dashboard where the analytics data such as Users, Sessions, Countries, are displayed.

Comment: Hi, have you found any solutions?